# How to find days left in a quarter using moment js

Tags: javascript, date, time, momentjs

I need to find days left in a quarter. From example `const quater = moment().quarter()` gives me a quarter number like 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 (depending on the current month ).

So my question, if the current month or day is in quarter 3 ( in a year ) , how to calculate that how many days still left in quarter 3 ? Kindly do help me to figure this out !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
console.log(moment().quarter());
var start = moment().startOf('quarter');
var end = moment().endOf('quarter');
console.log(start);
console.log(end);
console.log("daysLeft", moment(end).diff(moment(new Date()), 'days'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```